# Compile error wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment [VBA], Sheets highlighted in blue

Tags: excel, vba, properties, compilation, variable-assignment

The code runs without throwing an error message. It appears when I click on the Functional Lead Workbook(macro) button in the workbook. I only added three new resource groups to the code (Functional Safety Manager, Controls Engineering and Systems Engineering). Private Sub Create Functional Lead workbook was auto highlighted in yellow and on line 2607, the word Sheets is bolded in blue. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Create_Functional_Lead_Workbook()
' This function creates the Functional Lead Workbook from the existing Dashboard tabs.

2583: Dim vSheetNames, vSheet As Variant
2584: Dim sMessage, sSheetName As String
2585: Dim wbMaster As Workbook
2586: Dim astrLinks As Variant
2587: Dim i As Integer
2588: Dim UpdatingOn As Boolean

2590: If Not Me.Range("S41") Then On Error GoTo ErrTrap
2591: bAbort = False

2593: sSheetName = "Data Flow Project-Excel-Pro"
2594: UpdatingOn = Worksheets(sSheetName).Range("S39").Value

2596: Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

2598: Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook
2599: vSheetNames = Array("Product Line Management", "Program Management", "Product Engineering", "Industrialization", "Plant Operations", "Quality (Corporate)", "Quality (Site)", "Purchasing", "Sales", "Supply Chain", "IT(IS)", "Finance", "Legal", "Aftermarket", "Test Lab", "HR", "Customer Service", "Supplier Development", "Global Product Strategy", "Specifications", "Content Management", "Value Added Services", "Pricing", "Marketing", "Training Group", "Core Manager", "Cost Accounting", "PMO (Aft Mkt)", "Functional Safety Manager", "Controls Engineering", "Systems Engineering")

2601: For Each vSheet In vSheetNames
2602:    wbMaster.Worksheets(vSheet).Unprotect
2603: Next vSheet

'Copying Sheets to a new workbook.
2606: Application.StatusBar = "Copying Sheets to a new workbook."
2607: Sheets(Array("ImportedtoMSProjects", "Product Line Management", "Program Management", "Product Engineering", "Industrialization", "Plant Operations", "Quality (Corporate)", "Quality (Site)", "Purchasing", "Sales", "Supply Chain", "IT(IS)", "Finance", "Legal", "Aftermarket", "Test Lab", "HR", "Customer Service", "Supplier Development", "Global Product Strategy", "Specifications", "Content Management", "Value Added Services", "Pricing", "Marketing", "Training Group", "Core Manager", "Cost Accounting", "PMO (Aft Mkt)", "Functional Safety Manager", "Controls Engineering", "Systems Engineering")
```

Comment: It's missing another closing parenthesis in the end. You open 2 here `Sheets(Array(` but you only close one in the end `…, "Systems Engineering")`. You need to close both.

Comment: Please follow this procedure before posting code here.  1. Put option explicit at the start of each Class/Module/Form.  2. If you create late bound objects and use enumerations/constants from that object model you **must** manually declare those enumerations/constants.  3. Do a Debug.Compile Project and resolve any errors found. 4. When you get a clean compile look at the code inspections produced by the free and fantastic Rubber duck add in for VBA and resolve any relevant inspections

Comment: You're also missing a method call (I'm guessing `.Copy`?) on the end.